# Access SQL query: compare two tables to add data

Tags: database, ms-access, compare

I have tried to do this with vba in Excel, but I’ve given up and now I am trying to do it with a query in access.

The next tables 1 and 2 are only a sample, the actual ones have more than 26000 rows.

Table 1 was obtained from an automatic report in excel, then exported to access and used as template. All the columns are automatic, except the last one “surcharge” that was added manually in access.

Every week, a new report is generated (table 2)in excel with new rows and new prices (marked in orange) and exported to access, but I don't want to add every week the column surchage manually.

What I need to do is to modify table 2, in order to include with a query the column surcharge from the table 1 , whenever the company, city , product and ref number match in both tables.

[image]

In this way the new rows with gaps in column “surcharge” can be filled manually and then table 2 is saved as template until the following week when a new report will create a new table to be compared with.

Thanks for all your comments and support

Answer (score 0):

Very straightforward set of action queries. But you will need to use a staging table, like a table 3, to temporarily hold the new week data then migrate to table1 after processing. Below options uses a `INNER JOIN` query to match both tables:

**Option 1**: Delete (previous table 3 records - be sure to create the replica the very first time) / Append (to empty table 3) / Delete (previous table 1 records) / Append (to empty table 1) - *save each statement as separate stored queries and run them in sequence or script them as VBA string SQL statements also in sequence.*

```
DELETE FROM table3;

INSERT INTO table3 (company, city, product, surcharge)
SELECT t2.company, t2.city, t2.product, t1.surcharge
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1
ON t1.company = t2.company 
AND t1.city = t2.city 
AND t1.product = t2.product

DELETE FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table1 (company, city, product, surcharge)
SELECT company, city, product, surcharge
FROM table3;
```

**Option 2**: Make-Table query (into table3 - allow it to overwrite previous one) / Delete (previous records from table1) / Append (to empty table 1)

```
SELECT t2.company, t2.city, t2.product, t1.surcharge
INTO table3
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1
ON t1.company = t2.company 
AND t1.city = t2.city 
AND t1.product = t2.product

DELETE FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table1 (company, city, product, surcharge)
SELECT company, city, product, surcharge
FROM table3;
```